# PHP/HTML: Retaining text data after invalid form submit/ w/ placeholders

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have a working form with multiple fields, but am having issues with the placeholder and retaining user submitted text after a failed validation. Essentially the idea is to have:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first-name"
              value="<?php echo isset($_POST['first-name']) ? $first_name : ''; ?>  " >
```

retain the user's first name (For example: Jerry) after clicking submit. So if the user inputs incorrect data in a different field after submit, the first name "JERRY" will take the value of $first_name. This method works but unfortunately the value [$first_name : ''; ] applies a blank space which overrides the placeholder for the input field when a user opens the contact form for the first time. The user would have to erase the blank space in order to see the placeholder.

What would be a better way to retain submitted text data after validation with also having a placeholder visible?

Comment: Get rid of the space after your PHP closing tag.

Comment: This worked, hah. Thanks!